# Trouble accessing data from DataTable

Tags: c#

I've got a DataTable the I'm trying to access the DataRow row by row like so:

```
dataTable.Select("someID=" + someID.ToString()).CopyToDataTable().Rows.Count;
```

This works fine for someID of 0-9, but when I get to 10 I get a System.InvalidOperationException.  In Visual Studio DataTable Visualizer I can see someID as one of the columns with data of 0-24, so 10 should be there.

When I use the ImmediateWindow and look at `dataTable.Select("someID=10")` I get
   `{System.Data.DataRow[0]}` and looking at `dataTable.Select("someID=9")` gives me
    `{System.Data.DataRow[1]}`

What am I missing?

Comment: Immediate window shows that there is no row with `someID` equal to 10. It should be there, but it's not there. What are you trying to do with this query? Are you just checking if row exist?

Comment: someID shows up as a column header in the DataTable Visualizer window with one row having a 10 in that the someID column.

Comment: What is the result of this: `var result = string.Join(",", dataTable.Select().Select(r => r["someID"].ToString()).ToArray());` print the result for me and don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @RezaAghaei probably you want this `String.Join(",", dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("someId")))`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thanks for reminding `AsEnumerable` on `DataTable`, but `dataTable.Select()` works too, because `dataTable.Select()` returns `DataRow[]` and also I used `ToString()` because I don't know type of value and probably `Field<string>` is not suitable.

Comment: @RezaAghaei agree about `Field<string>`. But I suggest you to avoid `Select()` - it does big amount of work [behind the scene](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Select.cs,0c51d20a54f84737) while `AsEnumerable()` is simply `table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()`. It's not the case in this scenario, but keep it in mind :) And you don't need `ToArray()` - there is overload of `String.Join` which accepts `IEnumerable<string>` :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thank you, I usually use `Cast<DataRow>()` in my answers. It's long time that I didn't used DataTable myself ;).  Reading `Select()` documents, I saw it returns `Row[]` and I used it :)

Comment: @user2197446 And what was the result?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here are the results: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why do you need the `CopyToDataTable()` method when all you need is the count of matches? You could simply use the `Length` or `Count`, isn't it?

```
x = dataTable.Select("someID=" + someID.ToString()).Length;
```

Comment: True, but in this case I'm more worried about someID of 11 not being there, when I can see if via other means.  I'll change how I verify the number of rows however!

Comment: If your `someID` datacolumn is of string type, you may need to enclose the select expression (value part) in single quotes. e.g. `someID='11'`

Comment: that did the trick!  reading the comments under the question itself I'd like to know if there is also a better way to cycle through the elements.. Currently I'm using `foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Select("addressID='" + someID.ToString() + "'").CopyToDataTable().Rows)`

Comment: You don't need the `CopyToDataTable()` part; that adds an additional overhead. You should be directly able to use `foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Select("addressID='" + someID.ToString() + "'"))` unless ofcourse you really need a copy of the row instead of the row itself.